# Steps for Testflight to test an in app purchase on IOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, testflight

I cannot work out nor find up-to-date documentation that shows how to test in-app purchases on IOS using Testflight.

As far as I understand the use of Testflight negates the need for sandbox users. Testers can use their normal iTunes account details - correct?

I have enabled In-App Purchases for the app in the Developer Console.
I have uploaded In-App Purchases to iTunes Connect via Application Loader
The IAP are showing status 'Ready to submit'
The app itself is showing as 'prepare for submission' - it is way off submission yet, I'm just trying to test functionality.
The ID's of the IAP match those in the app code.

Is there anything else I need to do in iTunes Connect to get them working in Testflight builds?

Comment: Sounds like everything. You don't say what's not working.